# Hover text for suggested edit up/downvote buttons is incorrect

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, user-interface, tooltips

When I made a [suggested edit to an answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/142958) on Travel SE, I noticed that the hover text for the up/downvote buttons is the one for questions, not answers. See attached picture.

[image: hover text for questions instead of (proposed edits to) answers]